# .NET Core 5, Angular : how to manage date only and time only fields for a Postgresql database

Tags: angular, datetime, .net-core

C# has `DateTime` Type for both date only, time only database columns.
Typescript has `Date` type for both date only, time only columns.

Currently I'm having an issue using these two types for date only, time only purpose.

Has anyone had this issue before? Is there any workaround?